# Wordpress: edit only certain pages

Tags: wordpress, plugins, user-management

I know that this question has been asked already some times, but I'm not satisfied (as well as others) with the given answers so far.

I'm looking for a wordpress plugin that provides a sloild and easy-to-use functionality, that allocates certain pages to specific users. The best solution would be a new box on the editing page, where the admin can simply activate the users, which should be able to edit the current page. It's important that if you allocate a page to a user, which is not able to edit pages by default, that he/she gets the page menu item on the left where they can see all pages, they are able to edit.

Any ideas if there is a plugin that provides that functionality?

Comment: Have you googled what you are looking for? http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-access-manager/ that plugin sounds like it might work

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out Press Permit (http://wordpress.org/plugins/press-permit-core/) as a possible plugin, it seems to do what I need it to. A client has a site with 30 or so satellite councils that all want to edit their own data. Press Permit allows each to have a login that lets them edit only their page and nothing else.

There's also a Pro version but this seems to meet our needs pretty well.

Hope this one works out for ya!